# Add header to object or csv string

Tags: javascript, json, csv, object, papaparse

I'm using Papaparse with my csv (no header) string to give me an array of objects. I can parse the string without a header then change the keys or I can add a header string to my csv string and then parse that. I haven't had luck with either approach

```
var csvString = txtArea.value.trim();
var header = 'Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4';
csvString = header+csvString;
var objects = Papa.parse(csvString,{header:true});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must insert a linebreak `\n` between `header` and the CSV :

```
csvString = header+'\n'+csvString;
```

Then your code works and produces objects on the form

```
{ 
   "Header1" : "a",
   "Header2" : "b",
   ..
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rf1h0h10/**

Comment: @BumSon - see the fiddle, it works. But what exactly does not work for you?

Comment: The values in txtArea.value.trim(); are not separated by a comma. Seems to be a tab or space...